# Validation of viewstate MAC failed. Is it possible that not all viewstate is loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

On one of my servers which has quite a big trasffic Im receiving error: Validation of viewstate mac failed.

Is it possible that it happens because user submits form (for example by clicking asp:Button) before all viewstate is loaded ?

Thank You for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are hosting this app in a Web Farm or cluster make sure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. Remember that AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx) for complete root conditions of this type of error and suggested work arounds.

Comment: But it happens only if I click on submit really fast as soon as it appears. Problem doesnt happen if I wait a little

Comment: try the work around #2  by marking the form as disabled and then enable it in script once the load is complete:

  function enableForm() { 
      document.getElementById("form").disabled = false; 
  } 

  window.onLoad = enableForm();

Comment: But I was asking is it possible, cause if so, there would be billions of such exceptions worldwide

Comment: Absolutely!  Issue is evident if you have a large page which loads slowly for any reason.  If you also have datagrid or some databound controls on page which cause slowdown.  Essentially if your page is slow and you click a postback enabled control or link and the page hasn't loaded completely in client browser, you might get the "Validation of ViewState MAC failed" exception.